# « Seul X % » ou « seuls X % » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, pluriel

Je suis en train de relire le mémoire d'une amie. Celle-ci écrit à plusieurs reprises des phrases telles la suivante :

> Puis à partir de 60 ans, seul 2 % sont affectés.

Note : le « 2 % » se rapporte à une population de plusieurs millions d'individus.

Je me questionne quant au nombre du mot « seul ». Mon amie écrit-elle ce mot correctement, ou dois-je le remplacer par « seuls » ? Quelle est la règle à appliquer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ici, seul est un adjectif à valeur adverbiale, toutefois il fait exception à la règle d'invariabilité des adverbes.
La bonne orthographe est donc :

> seuls 2 % sont affectés.

Le fait que "seuls" soit suivi d'un pourcentage n'y change rien. On écrirait de même :

> Seuls sont affectés... Seuls les adultes sont... Seule une femme peut...

Cf. http://akilic.free.fr/concours/grammaire.pdf p28, je cite :

> [Les adverbes] sont invariables sauf [...] l'adjectif à valeur adverbiale *seul(e)* antéposé au sujet comme marqueur argumentatif d’exclusivité (*Seule la France a autant de vins différents*)

Answer (score 1):

Je suis entièrement d'accord avec la réponse de @user16924, parfaitement juste.
Je veux juste ajouter que même pour un francophone natif la règle laisse toujours planer un vague parfum de doute, parce qu'un peu contre-intuitive.

C'est pourquoi je suggère de contourner le problème en employant plutôt "seulement" :

> Puis à partir de 60 ans, seulement 2 % sont affectés.